# Aloe vera plant outgrowing its pot

Tags: transplanting, succulents, aloe

I have an aloe vera plant in a ceramic pot. It is growing too big for it and I'm not sure what to do. What is the procedure for transplanting aloe vera into a larger pot?

Also since it's so big, is there a way I can take part of it and start a new pot (like reproduce it)?

[image: photo 1]
[image: photo 2]

Comment: Do you use it for medicinal purposes? Burns, sunburn, lotion etc. that'll keep growth in check when cutting off leaves

Comment: The first part can be answered without an image, but as to taking it apart, we will need to see a picture.

Comment: @Stephie I have updated with pictures

Answer (score 2):

That's not really big, as aloes go. It'll get twice that big even in that little pot. However, I'd recommend transplanting it into a wide shallow pot, just so it isn't so easy to knock over. They're more-or-less a cactus, and thrive in well-drained, nutrient-poor soil. Anything just north of beach sand will do. I've grown them in everything from garden soil to paver base and they've always done just fine. I would assume cactus mix is probably best, but I'm too cheap to find out. Don't worry too much about transplant shock, they can bounce back from just about anything short of being completely pulverized.

Answer (score 1):

Your plant can be put into a larger pot with a drainage hole. When it has outgrown the pot it will give new plants you can plant apart.

I always put a 1 inch ball of clay on the bottom of the pot.